# Aligning content to the right using boostrap 4 and flexbox

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to align my header content to the right. 
{header content includes everything in the section tag}

I tried  adding align-items and align-content to the div tag including the "row" class, but the header content stays to the left.

I am also trying to keep this responsive using flexbox built into bootstrap 4.

Here is the link to my project: http://codeply.com/go/l8IZPmrIPa

I hoping to fix the issue of the content aligning left despite my efforts.

Comment: Have you tried with the `float-right` class?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for now. I'll build out the project and see how it holds up.